# Variant delimiting behavior depending on brackets wrapping string in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, hashset

I have the following (incorrect) code:

```
    this.MetadataProperties = new HashSet<string>(SplitMetadataProperties(metadataProperties));
    private static List<string> SplitMetadataProperties(string properties)
    {
        // Speed up accesses and splits
        char[] propertiesArray = properties.ToCharArray();

        // Look for a delimiter
        int bracketCount = 0;
        int start = 0;
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < propertiesArray.Length; ++i)
        {
            switch (properties[i])
            {
                case '[':
                    // Column open
                    bracketCount++;
                    break;
                case ']':
                    // Column close
                    bracketCount--;
                    break;
                case '|':
                    // Delimiter
                    if (bracketCount != 0)
                    {
                        // Treat this as a normal character, since it's not actually a delimiter. It's a part of a column.
                        break;
                    }

                    if (i > start)
                    {
                        // It's not empty, add it
                        int propertiesArrayLength = propertiesArray.Length - start;
                        result.Add(new string(propertiesArray, start, propertiesArrayLength));
                    }

                    // This is a delimiter. Split off this property and move to the next one
                    start = i + 1;
                    break;
            }

            // Add last item if needed
            if (start < propertiesArray.Length)
            {
                int propertiesArrayLength = propertiesArray.Length - start;
                result.Add(new string(propertiesArray, start, propertiesArrayLength));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Here's the desired behavior. Suppose we have:

```
string properties = "foo||||bar";
```

Desired result is:

```
expectedHashSet[0] = "foo";

expectedHashSet[1] = "bar";
```

However, right now I'm getting this:

```
"foo||||bar"
"|||bar"
"||bar"
"|bar"
"bar"
```

Note that if you have:

```
string properties = "[foo||||bar]";
```

then the desired result is instead the same exact string:

```
"[foo||||bar]";
```

"|" and "[" / "]" cause special behavior, hence the switch. I think the issue lies somewhere in the length calculations or related computation, but I'm not quite sure the exact change(s) I need. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are those the only two possible input patterns? What happens if there is no `|` or `[`? Can both occur (e.g. `[a||b]|c`)?

Comment: @NetMage So no | means no delimit. So "hiHello" is just "hiHello" as the expected return. As for stuff in [], it should just be returned the same way. 

Tl;dr no [] means eligible for delimit. If no [] AND no |, no delimit. If no [] AND |, delimit at |. Does this make sense?

Comment: Still vague, but clear enough perhaps.

Comment: BTW, can brackets be nested, such as `[[test|not]|abc]|foo|bar`?

Comment: @NetMage Good question: no

Comment: What about `abc[foo|bar]def`? Is it illegal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a state machine to parse the input. In this case, the state is inside `[`,`]` or outside. I normally like to create an `IEnumerable` state machine to return each parsed field, which can then be further processed as needed.

So, an extension method to handle your parsing:

```
public static class StringExt {
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitMetadataProperties(this string s) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool inQuote = false;
        foreach (var ch in s) {
            switch (ch) {
                case '[':
                    inQuote = true;
                    sb.Append(ch);
                    break;
                case ']':
                    inQuote = false;
                    sb.Append(ch);
                    break;
                case '|':
                    if (inQuote)
                        sb.Append(ch);
                    else {
                        if (sb.Length > 0) {
                            yield return sb.ToString();
                            sb.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    sb.Append(ch);
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (sb.Length > 0)
            yield return sb.ToString();
    }    
}
```

And, now you can parse your input and process as needed:

```
this.MetadataProperties = new HashSet<string>(metadataProperties.SplitMetadataProperties());
```

NOTE: I would normally use an extension method (that is included in the latest .Net):

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => new HashSet<T>(source);
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> cmp) => new HashSet<T>(source, cmp);
```

So you would have

```
this.MetadataProperties = metadataProperties.SplitMetadataProperties().ToHashSet();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the regular expressions solution here:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

And

```
private static IEnumerable<string> SplitMetadataProperties(string properties)
{
    string pattern = @"(\[.+\])|[^\|\s]+";
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(properties, pattern))
        yield return match.Value;
}
```

Now all you need is to define your `HashSet`

```
this.MetadataProperties = new HashSet<string>(SplitMetadataProperties(metadataProperties));
```

For the input:

```
[foo||||bar]
foo||||bar
[foo||||bar]
foo||||bar
foo|||bar
[foo||||bar]
[foo||||bar]
```

The output was:

```
[foo||||bar]
foo
bar
```

Pattern explanation:
Find either a string that starts with `[` and ends with `]` and have at least one character in between no matter what is it; or, a string with any character except for the delimiter (`|`) and white-spaces.

Comment: I now understand what he is asking for and your solution is nice. I would however suggest a slight addition to your method. I added the change as another reply (was not sure if I should edit yours). Good job.

Answer (score 0):

You want a list or array? For array:

```
    string properties = "foo||||bar";
if (!(properties.StartWith("[") && properties.EndWith("]"))
    {
var expectedHashSet = properties.Split(new char[] { '|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

For a List simply use .ToList().

Comment: You don't seem to be handling `[`,`]` as needed.

Comment: This also doesn't work because you can have multiple things encased with [] in the properties string. So like "hiHello|[HiHello]" is valid, but doesn't start AND end with []. You'd want this return:
hiHello, [HiHello]

Comment: @CourtneyThurston, sorry I don't understand your rules explanation. You dropped [HiHello] in last case and I can't understand the logic. Probably you need some RegEx implementation.

Comment: Hm? It was not dropped. Expected return is hiHello, [HiHello]. Or if properties string was "hi|hello|[hi|hello]", return should be: hi, hello, [hi|hello]

Comment: Oh yes, you edited it and not dropped. But again this time it became hiHello, [HiHello]. And hi|Hello|[hi|hello] becomes hi, hello, [hi|hello] based on some logic that I don't understand (where did those space and commas came from? for example)

Comment: @CetinBasoz That's just meant to indicate these are different entries in the hashSet.

Answer (score 0):

I think I now understand what you are asking. This one is actually based on Aly El-Haddad's reply, only made a slight addition for edge cases.

```
void Main()
{
    string properties = "foo||||bar[as|is]ak|yak[yet|another]ll";
    foreach (var t in SplitMetadataProperties(properties))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(t); 
    } 
}

private static IEnumerable<string> SplitMetadataProperties(string properties)
{
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(properties, @"\[.+?\]"))
    {
        properties = properties.Replace(m.Value, "|" + m.Value + "|");
    }

    string pattern = @"(\[.+?\])|[^\|\s]+";

    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(properties, pattern))
    {
        yield return match.Value;
    }
}
```